# Getting first key-value pair from Map without using <c:forEach>

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

How do I get the first key-value pair from a `Map` without using `<c:forEach>`?

Comment: Best way: you add a method `getFirstEntry()` in the object containing the map, and use `${theObject.firstEntry}`. In recent JSP EL versions, you should be able to simply do `${map.entrySet().iterator().next()}`. I hope you're aware that several map implementations don't have any order, and that this will thus return an arbitrary entry of the map.

Comment: @JBNizet could you post your comment as an answer as it is the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

Best way: you add a method `getFirstEntry()` in the object containing the map, and use `${theObject.firstEntry}`.

In recent JSP EL versions, you should be able to simply do `${map.entrySet().iterator().next()}`.

I hope, though, that you're aware that several (most) map implementations don't have any order, and that this will thus return an arbitrary entry of the map.